# Malloc in C - return value

Tags: c, function, pointers, return

I have this code sample, and generally understand its logic, but am stuck in some details.

```
#define LSH_RL_BUFSIZE 1024
char *lsh_read_line(void) {
  int bufsize = LSH_RL_BUFSIZE;
  int position = 0;
  char *buffer = malloc(sizeof(char) * bufsize);
  int c;

  if (!buffer) {
    fprintf(stderr, "lsh: allocation error\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  while (1) {
    // Read a character
    c = getchar();

    // If we hit EOF, replace it with a null character and return.
    if (c == EOF || c == '\n') {
      buffer[position] = '\0';
      return buffer;
    } else {
      buffer[position] = c;
    }
    position++;

    // If we have exceeded the buffer, reallocate.
    if (position >= bufsize) {
      bufsize += LSH_RL_BUFSIZE;
      buffer = realloc(buffer, bufsize);
      if (!buffer) {
        fprintf(stderr, "lsh: allocation error\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I cannot understand two things: Firstly, what exactly does this line do?

```
char *buffer = malloc(sizeof(char) * bufsize)
```

And secondly, how does the following line work? How is it that a pointer can be returned?

```
return buffer;
```

Comment: "How can we return a pointer?" Just using the way you can return a integer. Are there any reason you think you cannot do that?

Comment: [`malloc`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc) asks the OS for a chunk of memory specified by its parameter (in this case, `bufsize`). You return a pointer just like you would any other value from a function, the details of which depend on the [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface)

Comment: I mean , what does it gives us practicaly in this example ?

Comment: `return buffer;` returns the pointer to the memory that was `malloc`ed

Comment: Note that `old_ptr = realloc(old_ptr, new_size)` is an anti-pattern.  If the memory allocation fails, you have a null pointer in `old_ptr`, but the memory it was (but is no longer) pointing to is still allocated to the program.  You muse use `new_ptr = realloc(old_ptr, new_size); if (new_ptr == 0) { …handle error… } old_ptr = new_ptr;` to protect against memory leaks.

Comment: You declared a return type `char *` for the function `lsh_read_line(void)`, therfore the function must return a `char *` pointer at the end of execution.

Answer (score 3):

> what exactly does this line do?

`malloc` means "memory allocation"
`malloc` function is used to dynamically create a memory block, it allocates a memory block of size  specified in bytes (as a parameter). It returns a pointer to the beginning of that block.

So the specified size here is '`sizeof(char) * bufsize`' i.e. a block of characters of length '`bufsize`' is being requested. To get a size of 1 character you use the operator sizeof (sizeof is an operator not a function)

> how does the following line work?

the function `lsh_read_line` returns pointer to a memory block, which is the memory allocated by `malloc` here - and it is `buffer`.

> How is it that a pointer can be returned?

Since it is dynamic memory from the heap - it is valid memory block even after the function returns.

As a side note - '`lsh_read_line`' caller must free this `buffer` otherwise there is a memory leak!

For further details on **C Function stack** please refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack